# Some labels for input fields with invalid input turn red some don't

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I have a bunch of input fields in a JSF form with associated labels and validators.

On some fields a failing validation turns the label red on some it doesn't.

Any idea where the cause for that might be, or how to debug that?

I verified that the lable/input relationship is set up properly by clicking the label and observing that the focus goes to the respective input field.

We use JSF-2.0 and Primefaces 5

This one turns red:

```
        <p:column style="width:10em;">
            <f:facet name="header">
              <span
                title="#{messages['tooltip.model.modelSearch.modelKeyPattern']}">
                <p:outputPanel>
                  <p:outputLabel
                    id="modelKeyPatternLabel"
                    for="modelKeyPattern"
                    styleClass="control-label"
                    value="#{messages['label.model.modelSearch.modelKey']}" />
                  <p:inputText
                    id="modelKeyPattern"
                    value="#{modelSearchBean.modelKeyPattern}"
                    validatorMessage="#{messages['error.model.modelSearch.modelKey']}"
                    size="6"
                    styleClass="searchField">
                    <f:validateLength maximum="6" />
                  </p:inputText>
                </p:outputPanel>
              </span>
            </f:facet>
```

This one doesn't:

```
          <p:column style="width:6em;">
            <f:facet name="header">
              <span
                title="#{messages['tooltip.model.modelSearch.modelYear']}">
                <p:outputPanel>
                  <h:outputLabel
                    id="modelYearLabel"
                    for="modelYear"
                    styleClass="control-label"
                    value="#{messages['label.model.modelSearch.table.column.modelYear']}" />
                  <p:inputText
                    id="modelYear"
                    value="#{modelSearchBean.modelYear}"
                    validator="#{modelYeaValidator.validate}"
                    styleClass="searchField"
                    size="4">
                  </p:inputText>
                </p:outputPanel>
              </span>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{model.modelYear}" />
          </p:column>
```

Comment: do you see any javascript error in your console (Using firefox debug console)?

Comment: @Makky there are no errors in the console

Comment: Is `modelYeaValidator.validate()` invoked properly ?

Comment: @Omar Yes. Get's called with the expected value and throws a ValidatorException when the value is not valid.

Comment: When throwing that exception, do you send your custom validation error message (instance of `FacesMessage`) with that constructor (as parameter) ?

Comment: @Omar Yes I do. I found the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The red label is a `h:outputLabel` while the other one is a `p:outputLabel`. Note the difference between `p:` and `h:`

Comment: Annoying mistake it was.